# Don't understand why I am getting index out of bounds exception when filling this 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

```
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.charAt(0) != '#') {
                c++;
                // looking to get dimensions from file.
                // getting size of array from lines of input.
                dimensions = new int[c][4];

                // Split my file input into an array of tokens(strings)
                tokens = line.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    // Parse strings to int.
                    dimtoke[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
                }

                int n = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < dimensions.length; k++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
                        // Error here when trying to put dimtoke into dimensions
                        (ERROR HERE)dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[n];

                        n++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The for loop to fill the dimensions array runs twice correctly, on the third iteration however, I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:4 exception and I can't figure why.  The size of the 2d array is correct, I need that counter n so that i can go through dimtoke array and it should reset itself each time through the while loop. 
(This is all contained in a try/catch block, but couldn't add the 'try' for formatting issues on this sight.)

Here's the stack trace.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at P1.readLineSegments(P1.java:49)
    at P1.main(P1.java:16)
```

Comment: Is it C#? Shouldn't be   dimensions = new int[c,4];  instead of   dimensions = new int[c][4]; ?

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception. ALWAYS. Tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: What is the contents of the file? How is `dimtoke` allocated?

Comment: OK, so now put a breakpoint at this line, start the program using the debugger, and inspect the value of all the variables to see what happens.

Comment: What is dimtoke.length?  Most likely, you're running out of input - if dimtoke.length < c * 4, you'll see that exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have n++ in the wrong spot.

```
int n = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < dimensions.length; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
        // Error here when trying to put dimtoke into dimensions
        (ERROR HERE)dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[n];
    }
    n++; //it should be here
}
```

Where you have n++ it will go up 16 if it is a 4x4 array.

Answer (score 0):

it can be `dimensions[k][j]` or `dimtoke[n]`. `k` is the length of dimension so it is out of question. `j` is 0..3 ( if it is as simple as code shows. so `dimensions[0].length` can be replaced with 4.)

the only problem is with `dimtoke[n]` and it seems size of your tokens are less than `4 * dimensions.length`

Comment: That fixed the array out of bounds error, but now dimtoke isn't filling into dimensios correctly.  I only get the last line of text from the file that i want, in the first row of dimensions instead of it filling all the data i want into dimensions.

Comment: are u aware that u are actually making new instances of dimensions and dimtoke for each line u read? that could be the exact reason why u only have the last line in your results